# what is causing this javascript code to function the way it is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know stackoverflow tends to shy away from "wall of text" posts, but I've been at this for about 4 hours and I can't figure it out, so I wanted to give as much information as possible.

I have a page with two input forms on it.  Whenever I add text into the first one, **the javascript function attached to the second input button runs, and I can't figure out why.**

In my header I have two scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/autocomplete/js/script.js"></script>
```

which contains:

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'capoInstantSearch.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item

function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#country_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#country_list_id').hide();

  $("#capoInfo").load("capoSingleReturn.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(item));  

}
```

capoInstantSearch.php looks like this:

```
<?php

function connect() {
    return new PDO('code here to connect'}

$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT statement is here....";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $country_name = str_replace(strtoupper($_POST['keyword']), '<b>'.$_POST['keyword'].'</b>', $rs['quotePartNumber']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['quotePartNumber']).'\')">'.$country_name.'</li>';
}
?>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/autocomplete/js/script2.js"></script>
```

which contains:

```
function compCheck() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var bootyTime = $('#comp_id').val();
    if (bootyTime.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'capoInstantCompSearch.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {bootyTime:bootyTime},
            success:function(data){
                $('#comp_list_id').show();
                $('#comp_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#comp_list_id').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#comp_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#comp_list_id').hide();
  $("#compReturn").load("capoCompReturn.php?w="+encodeURIComponent(item));
}
```

Input Box 1:

```
<input id="country_id" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Part Number"
onsubmit="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="autocomplet()">
<ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
```

Input Box 2:

```
<input id="comp_id" type="text" onkeypress="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" 
placeholder="Part Number 2" onkeyup="compCheck()"></h2>
<ul id="comp_list_id"></ul>
```

Ultimately, the contents of autocomplet() should be placed into this div

```
<div id="capoInfo" class="capoData"></div>
```

while the contents of compCheck() should be placed into

```
<div id="compReturn" class="blueBorder"></div>
```

When I type text into the first input box, it populates the `<ul>` country_list_id, and when I make a selection, it populates that answer into second input box on my page, then executes that code.  I cannot figure out WHY it is doing this and it's driving me crazy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have two functions that are in the global scope called "set_item"

Comment: god...... something so simple......... 5 seconds > 4 hours... I should have asked a while ago. :)  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your functions in the global scope, and the second is overwriting the first. You could solve this by namespacing (for lack of a better term) your functions by sticking them into an object.

For example,

**script.js**

```
var country = {

    autocomplete: function() {
        var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
        var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
        if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'capoInstantSearch.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {keyword:keyword},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#country_list_id').show();
                    $('#country_list_id').html(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#country_list_id').hide();
        }
    },

    // set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
    set_item: function(item) {
        // change input value
        $('#country_id').val(item);
        // hide proposition list
        $('#country_list_id').hide();

      $("#capoInfo").load("capoSingleReturn.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(item));  

    }
}
```

**script2.js**

```
var comp = {

    compCheck: function() {
        var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
        var bootyTime = $('#comp_id').val();
        if (bootyTime.length >= min_length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'capoInstantCompSearch.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {bootyTime:bootyTime},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#comp_list_id').show();
                    $('#comp_list_id').html(data);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#comp_list_id').hide();
        }
    },

    // set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
    set_item: function(item) {
        // change input value
        $('#comp_id').val(item);
        // hide proposition list
        $('#comp_list_id').hide();
      $("#compReturn").load("capoCompReturn.php?w="+encodeURIComponent(item));
    }

}
```

and then change the references in your HTML to include the namespace, e.g.

**input box 1** (note the `onkeyup`)

```
<input id="country_id" type="text" placeholder="Enter a Part Number"
onsubmit="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="country.autocomplete()">
<ul id="country_list_id"></ul>
```

and then repeat for all the other references, including the one in the PHP code.

You may also want to check out Browserify which brings Node's `require` module syntax to the browser. Additionally, you might read up on closures and IIFE's in JS.

Comment: I ended up going with the other solution (mainly because I saw it first.)  This is really interesting though - and it's a big help in my understanding of Javascript.  I really appreciate the time you've taken to write this out for me!