# Autocomplete ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

```
        <script>

function autocomplet1() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#select01').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'barcode.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#barcode01').show();
                $('#barcode01').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#barcode01').hide();
    }
}

function set_item(item2) {
    $('#select01').val(item2);
    var customer = $("#customer").val();
    $.post("sales/add", {"data[Sales][item]": item2 ,"data[Sales][customer_phone]": customer  }, function (data) {
      $('#details3').html(data);
       $("#select01").val('');
});
    // hide proposition list
    $('#barcode01').hide();
}
</script>

<script>
// autocomplet : this function will be executed every time we change the text
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#customer').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'abc.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}
function set_item(item1) {
    $('#customer').val(item1);
    $.post("sales/add", {"data[Sales][customer]": item1 }, function (data) {
      $('#details').html(data);
});
    // hide proposition list
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
}
</script>


 <div class="input_container">


             <input type="text"  id='customer' onkeyup="autocomplet()" name="data[Sales][customer]" class="input-small focused">
                    <ul id="country_list_id" style='height: 500px;'></ul></div></div>
<div class="content">
         <div class="input_container">


             <input type="text"  id='select01' onkeyup="autocomplet1()" name="data[Sales][item]" class="input-small focused">
                    <ul id="barcode01" style='height: 500px;'></ul></div></div>
```

Above is an autocomplete script. Both script having same function set_time . If i changed function name as set_time1, then autocomplete is not working . How to resolve this issue? . I need to use two autocomplete  in a single page.

Comment: I can see no `set_time` or `set_time1` function in your script. But you declare twice a function with the same name `function set_item`, the second overrides the first one. So the first one just can't be called.

Comment: actually two script having same function set_item . Now to tell me how to change it .. Totally there are two function set_time is there . that's why script is not working properly

Comment: It's not "two scripts" because it's all part of the same page so it's all the same script. Two functions with the same name just can't work in javascript because the second definition will override the first one. Please show me the "set_time" function, because you confirm it's here, and I confirm I can't find it.

Comment: my question is as same as this .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27389241/what-is-causing-this-javascript-code-to-function-the-way-it-is

Comment: Nice, a duplicate. And my answer is exactly the same, if you read it.

Comment: If i changed  like that link .. But still its not working :( . Can you replace my script . I am fresher for this jquery-ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since this is hard to explain in the tiny comments, I'll write it here.

Take that script :

```
function set_item(){
   alert("Hello!");
}

function set_item(){
   alert("Goodbye!");
}

set_item();
```

What do you think will happen? What will be alerted?
Answer : "Goodbye!", because the second function definition overrode the first one. You will never see the "Hello!" alert.

This is what happens when two functions have the same name. And you have two functions with the same name. Placing them in different `<script>` tags won't change anything, it's still the same scope.

Comment: Goodbye alert is displaying . But i need to display based on id . If id is customer set_item function is different . if it is select01 id then set_item function is different . How to write query for this .

Comment: Write two functions and give them a DIFFERENT NAME! I don't know how to explain it better, is it so hard to understand? Sorry but I'm running out of arguments here